# Form element not returning new value

Tags: javascript, forms, textinput

I am attempting to create a script that allows the user to click a `div` element with an `h1`'d bit of text and then replace the `h1` with a textbox and a graphic to click after editing. Once the graphic is clicked, the `div` will replace the textbox and graphic with the newly edited `h1`'d bit of text.

Here are the functions:

```
function savename() {
    var s = $('#mytextbox').val();
    $('#mydiv').replaceWith('<div id="mydiv" onclick="editname();"><h1>' + s + '</h1></div>');
}
function editname() {
    var strName = $('#mydiv').text();
    $('#mydiv').replaceWith($('<div id="mydiv"><input id="mytextbox" name="mytextbox" type="text" value="' + strName + '"><img id="mysavebutton" src="images/save.gif" onclick="savename();"></div>'));
}
```

And here is the div:

```
<div id="mydiv" onclick="editname();"><h1>Some text I want to edit</h1></div>
```

So, the `div` click function works fine. It replaces the `h1` element with a textbox. And when I click the save graphic, that works fine too, in that it returns the `h1`. The problem is, the value of the textbox is supposed to be the `h1`'d text. That part's not working. It still retains the old value. I put an alert for "s" after setting it to `.val()` and it still shows the old value, even after editing. I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I've fought with it all day and need some fresh eyes to look at it for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/cwfhY/2/

Comment: I should have clarified that the div with the h1 inside appears first. Your test started with an input box. However, that didn't change anything when I edited your test. Turns out it's because I had it inside a form. Once I put the div outside the form, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing the mydiv and trying to re-creating mydiv, why don't you just hide mydiv on click and change the value of the h1 tag when you try to save?

In the html you can have something like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <h1 id="myoutput" onclick="editname();"> ... </h1>
    <input id="mytextbox" name="mytextbox" type="text" style="display:none;">
    <img id="mysavebutton" src="images/save.gif" onclick="savename();" style="display:none" /> 
</div>
```

Then in javascript:

```
function editname()
{
    var s = $('#myoutput').text();
    $('#myoutput').css('display', 'none');
    $('#mytextbox').val(s).css('display','inline');
    $('#mysavebutton').css('display', 'inline');
}
function savename()
{
    var s = $('#mytextbox').val();
    $('#myoutput').text(s).css('display', 'inline');
    $('#mytextbox').css('display', 'none');
    $('#mysavebutton').css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: I had thought about that and probably will change the production code to work like that, but I was determined to figure out why the edit wasn't working. As I said in my comment to Fabricio, it turns out that wrapping it in a form was the problem. So, while your method is cleaner, it wouldn't have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and is native ES5 (ECMAScript 5 Spec) - no libraries

([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tenru/))

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    "use strict";

    var divElem = document.getElementById("div"),
        textInputElem = document.createElement("input"),
        buttonElem = document.createElement("input");

    textInputElem.type = "text";
    buttonElem.type = "button";
    buttonElem.value = "Apply";

    function removeChildren(elem) {
        while (elem.firstChild) {
            elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
        }
    }

    function divClick() {
        removeChildren(divElem);
        divElem.appendChild(textInputElem, divElem.firstChild);
        divElem.appendChild(buttonElem);
        divElem.removeEventListener("click", divClick, true);
    }

    buttonElem.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var textNode;

        if (textInputElem.value !== "") {
            removeChildren(divElem);
            textNode = document.createTextNode(textInputElem.value);
            divElem.appendChild(textNode);
            divElem.addEventListener("click", divClick, true);
        }
    }, false);
    divClick();
}, false);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div"></div>​
```

Here is the MDN doc on Element.AddEventListener(): [MDN: AddEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)